# How to execute the url of each individual machine every x minutes?

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, scheduledexecutorservice

I am working on a project in which I have three datacenters -  `DC1`, `DC2` and `DC3`.

In `DC1` I have 2 machines `(machineA and machineB)`, in `DC2` I have two machine `(machineC and machineD)` and in `DC3` I have two machines again `(machineE and machineF)`.

Each machine URL in each datacenter is like this and it returns back the string as the response -

```
http://machineName:8080/textbeat
```

For DC1-

```
http://machineA:8080/textbeat
http://machineB:8080/textbeat
```

For DC2-

```
http://machineC:8080/textbeat
http://machineD:8080/textbeat
```

For DC3-

```
http://machineE:8080/textbeat
http://machineF:8080/textbeat
```

Here is the response string I see in general after hitting the url for any particular machine -

```
state: READY server_uptime: 12462125 data_syncs: 29
```

**Problem Statement:-**

Now I need to iterate all the machines in each datacenters and execute the URL and then extract `data_syncs` from it. And this has to be done every 1 minute.

And now if `machineA` `data_syncs` is always zero continuously for a period of 5 minutes, then I would like to print `DC1` and `machineA`. Similarly for machineB and other datacenters.

The logic that I was thinking -

- Ping each individual machine from each datacenter, extract the `data_syncs` value if it is zero, increment the counter by one,
- Then try again after one minute, if the value is still zero, increment the same counter again by one.
- If the counter reaches 5 (as it is 5 minutes) and it was still zero continuously, then I would add this machine and datacenter name in my map.
- But suppose during three continuous tries it was zero and in fourth try it became non zero, then my counter will get reset to zero for that machine in the datacenter and start the process again for that machine.

Below is my map in which I am putting the datacenter and its machines if they have met above condition -

```
final Map<String, List<String>> holder = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Here key is the datacenter name and value is the list of machines for that datacenter which has met the condition.

Below is the code I came up with to solve the above problem but it doesn't work the way as I am supposed to do I guess. Here my `counter` is same for all the machines I guess which is not what I want.

```
public class MachineTest {

    private static int counter = 0;
    private final static ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final ScheduledFuture<?> taskUtility = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    generalUtility();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // log an exception
                }
            }
        }, 0, 1L, TimeUnit.MINUTES); 

    }

    protected static void generalUtility() {
        try {
            final Map<String, List<String>> holder = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();

            List<String> datacenters = Arrays.asList("DC1", "DC2", "DC3");
            for (String datacenter : datacenters) {
                LinkedList<String> machines = new LinkedList<String>();

                List<String> childrenInEachDatacenter = getMachinesInEachDatacenter(datacenter);

                for (String hosts : childrenInEachDatacenter) {
                    String host_name = hosts;
                    String url = "http://" + host_name + ":8080/textbeat";

                    MachineMetrics metrics = GeneralUtilities.getMetricsOfMachine(host_name, url); // execute the url and populate the MachineMetrics object
                    if (metrics.getDataSyncs().equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                        counter++;
                        if (counter == 5) {
                            machines.add(hosts);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(!machines.isEmpty()) {
                    holder.put(datacenter, machines);   
                }
            }

            if (!holder.isEmpty()) {
                // log the datacenter and its machine as our criteria is met
                System.out.println(holder);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    // Below method will return list of machines given the name of datacenter
    private static List<String> getMachinesInEachDatacenter(String datacenter) {
        // this will return list of machines for a given datacenter
    }

}
```

And here is my `MachineMetrics` class -

```
public class MachineMetrics {

    private String machineName;
    private String dataSyncs;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Is this possible to do using ScheduledExecutorService as this is not one time process? It has to be done repeatedly

Basically for each machine if `data_syncs` is 0 for a period of `5 minutes` **continuously** then I need to log that datacenter and its machines.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Machine{
    private String dataCenter;
    private String machineName;
    private String hostname;
    private int zeroCount = 0;

    //getters setters, except for zeroCount
    // constructor with datacenter,machine as args

    private boolean isEligibleForLogging(String dataSyncs){
        if(dataSyncs.equals("0")){
            zeroCount++;
        }else{
            zeroCount = 0;
        }   

        if(zeroCount > 5){
            zeroCount = 0;
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }
}


static List<Machine> machines = new ArrayList<Machine>();

static{
    Machine machine1 = new Machine("DC1", "name1","hostname1");
    machines.add(machine1);
    //repeat the above two lines per each machine.
}


protected static void generalUtility() {
    try {

        for (Machine machine : machines) {

                String host_name = machine.getHostName();
                String url = "http://" + host_name + ":8080/textbeat";

                String dataSyncs = //execute url and get datasyncs
                if(machine.isEligibleForLogging()){
                    System.out.println(machine.getName() + ... +machine.getDataCenter() + ... + dataSyncs......);
                }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Chamil. In your Machine class, do we need `dataSyncs` variable? Secondly, what will happen in that situation - Suppose for the first time, `dataSyncs` was `zero` for a particular machine so zeroCount will be `1` but next time it was not zero, then still it will be one for that machine Right? If yes, then I guess that's not what I need, it should be continuous 5 tries.

Comment: Thanks what about my second question? Any thoughts? -  Suppose for the first time, dataSyncs was zero for a particular machine so zeroCount will be 1 but next time it was not zero, then still it will be one for that machine Right? If yes, then I guess that's not what I need, it should be continuous 5 tries.

Comment: updated! If dataSyncs is non zero, the zeroCount resets. Now no problem I guess.

Comment: One more quick question. Here `generalUtility` will be called by my background thread every minute in your example. Right? If yes, then how does `zeroCount` will remain same for that particular machine every one minute? Just confuse.

Comment: Good thinking @SSH ! I have moved the machine List as a global field so that it will remain until your program runs.